# VBA Code to communicate with a Human Interface Device (HID)

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, hid, rfid

I have recently bought a RFID R/W device, and I would like to send and receive data from it to a VBA application that I have already developed. I have been looking for a solution, but I was not able to find any.

I would like to know if there are any VBA instructions for receiving and sending data to a HID. If not, which would be the simplest way to communicate with my device? The code would be very simple, just writing and reading hex code. I could manage an application in vb or C# too.

The driver has been correctly installed and their specs. are in the link: http://www.securakey.com/PRODUCTS/RFID_PRODUCTS/ET4AUS_D_AUM_7656.pdf

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done VBA programming but you will be able to use the same Windows API calls that C# or VB.Net use. Here is some example code for enumerating Hid devices and connecting. You will need to translate to VBA. This is a link on Windows API in VBA https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/31727/windows-api---dedicated-module--1-of-2-.

Here is Windows API code for enumerating Hid devices:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Device.Net/Windows/WindowsDeviceFactoryBase.cs

```
           var deviceDefinitions = new Collection<DeviceDefinition>();
            var spDeviceInterfaceData = new SpDeviceInterfaceData();
            var spDeviceInfoData = new SpDeviceInfoData();
            var spDeviceInterfaceDetailData = new SpDeviceInterfaceDetailData();
            spDeviceInterfaceData.CbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(spDeviceInterfaceData);
            spDeviceInfoData.CbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(spDeviceInfoData);

            var guidString = ClassGuid.ToString();
            var copyOfClassGuid = new Guid(guidString);

            var i = APICalls.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref copyOfClassGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.DigcfDeviceinterface | APICalls.DigcfPresent);

            if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
            {
                spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.CbSize = 8;
            }
            else
            {
                spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.CbSize = 4 + Marshal.SystemDefaultCharSize;
            }

            var x = -1;

            while (true)
            {
                x++;

                var isSuccess = APICalls.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(i, IntPtr.Zero, ref copyOfClassGuid, (uint)x, ref spDeviceInterfaceData);
                if (!isSuccess)
                {
                    var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (errorCode == APICalls.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    throw new Exception($"Could not enumerate devices. Error code: {errorCode}");
                }

                isSuccess = APICalls.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(i, ref spDeviceInterfaceData, ref spDeviceInterfaceDetailData, 256, out _, ref spDeviceInfoData);
                WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, "Could not get device interface detail");

                //Note this is a bit nasty but we can filter Vid and Pid this way I think...
                var vendorHex = vendorId?.ToString("X").ToLower().PadLeft(4, '0');
                var productIdHex = productId?.ToString("X").ToLower().PadLeft(4, '0');
                if (vendorId.HasValue && !spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.DevicePath.ToLower().Contains(vendorHex)) continue;
                if (productId.HasValue && !spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.DevicePath.ToLower().Contains(productIdHex)) continue;

                var deviceDefinition = GetDeviceDefinition(spDeviceInterfaceDetailData.DevicePath);

                deviceDefinitions.Add(deviceDefinition);
            }

            APICalls.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(i);

            return deviceDefinitions;
```

Here is connection code:

```
public bool Initialize()
{
    Dispose();

    if (DeviceInformation == null)
    {
        throw new WindowsHidException($"{nameof(DeviceInformation)} must be specified before {nameof(Initialize)} can be called.");
    }

    var pointerToPreParsedData = new IntPtr();
    _HidCollectionCapabilities = new HidCollectionCapabilities();
    var pointerToBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(126);

    _ReadSafeFileHandle = APICalls.CreateFile(DeviceInformation.DeviceId, APICalls.GenericRead | APICalls.GenericWrite, APICalls.FileShareRead | APICalls.FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    _WriteSafeFileHandle = APICalls.CreateFile(DeviceInformation.DeviceId, APICalls.GenericRead | APICalls.GenericWrite, APICalls.FileShareRead | APICalls.FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.OpenExisting, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

    if (!HidAPICalls.HidD_GetPreparsedData(_ReadSafeFileHandle, ref pointerToPreParsedData))
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not get pre parsed data");
    }

    var getCapsResult = HidAPICalls.HidP_GetCaps(pointerToPreParsedData, ref _HidCollectionCapabilities);

    //TODO: Deal with issues here

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointerToBuffer);

    var preparsedDataResult = HidAPICalls.HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref pointerToPreParsedData);

    //TODO: Deal with issues here

    if (_ReadSafeFileHandle.IsInvalid)
    {
        return false;
    }

    _ReadFileStream = new FileStream(_ReadSafeFileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, _HidCollectionCapabilities.OutputReportByteLength, false);
    _WriteFileStream = new FileStream(_WriteSafeFileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, _HidCollectionCapabilities.InputReportByteLength, false);

    IsInitialized = true;

    RaiseConnected();

    return true;
}
```